# Freenas & LDAP Multiple User Groups Not Taking Affect

Tags: ldap, file-permissions, truenas

we are using, Freenas 9.2.1.7 which communicates with LDAP to control file permission.

We have Windows users in multiple groups. Some belong to Finance as their primary group and Admin as another group they belong to. They can only access files from their Primary group.

We use LDAP Account Manager - 4.4 to control which group the users belong to.

We have also been trying to control access from the command line. We hae tried using this :

setfacl -m group@:rwWxpaRc::allow DIR / Or File Name

The problem is only the primary group is being seen / used. I am trying to determine why only on group is being used.

Can someone please help me diagnose where the problem is.

Thanks for the help,

Dan

Comment: This might be off-topic, but I prefer to attach the volume via iSCSI and share it via SMB with all the security features Windows natively offers. (If the NAS is located at a site with a Windows server.

Comment: I got it working but I had to remove the ACLs set with setfacl. The standard Linux permissions wrx respect the different permissions for the groups.